# mysqli query return not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been working on a site on XAMPP while developing, now I've uploaded the site to the hosting and the return is not working, but only for the table.

This is the XAMPP view:

[image]

And this is the hosting view:

[image]

I know the connection is working because the filters on the right, those selects are populated by the return of a select, and they work both on XAMPP and the hosting.

Now here is the code:

This is the Model Food.php:

```
    public function showAll()
{
        // creating a database connection
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        return $this->db_connection->query("SELECT * FROM food ORDER BY price_food ASC;");
        var_dump($sql);
}
```

And this is the table on View food.php

```
    <style type="text/css">
  table {
    font-size:16px;

  }
</style>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>
        <center>Contenedor</center>
        </th>
        <th>
        <center>Animal</center>
        </th>
        <th>
        <center>Segmento</center>
        </th>
        <th>
        <center>Marca</center>
        </th>
        <th>
        <center>Sabor</center>
        </th>
        <th>
        <center>Peso</center>
        </th>
        <th>
        <center>Precio</center>
        </th>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($food->showAll() as $food_table) {
?>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <center><?= $food_table["container_food"]?></center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center><?= $food_table["animal_name_food"]?></center>
    </td>
    <td style="width:20%;">
        <center><?= $food_table["animal_segment_food"]?></center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center><?= $food_table["brand_food"]?></center>
    </td>
    <td style="width:20%;">
        <center><?= $food_table["flavor_food"]?></center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center><?= $food_table["weight_food"]?></center>
    </td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;">
        <center>$ <?= $food_table["price_food"]?></center>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>
```

I can't see the problem, this is the first time I am working on a real hosting environment so after researching a lot of MySQLi and PHP, I just don´t know what is wrong.

Any help is welcome, Thank you.

Comment: You don't check for errors. Use `mysqli->error` to see if there is a db error of some kind.

Comment: Check if PHP allows for short open tags `<?` and `?>`

Comment: I tried <?php and <?php echo, neither worked

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I tried a different approach and it worked, I still don't get why it worked on XAMPP and not on the hosting.

Here is the working code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM food ORDER BY price_food ASC;";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;

/* free result set */
$result->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```